# Eclipse Scout User Login

Tags: eclipse-scout

I have a Eclipse Scout 8.0 application and I want to allow users to login with information stored in my database. I have done a lot of looking and everything I have found is for version 3.8

Comment: Please provide code to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Scout HelloWorld project using the Eclipse Project Wizard or the Maven archetype "scout-helloworld-app", login and logout functionality is created as well. You will find a class `UiServletFilter` which handles the authentication. This filter uses a so called `IAccessController` which checks if the user is already authenticated, and if not, verifies its credentials by using an `ICredentialVerifier`. By default, the `ConfigFileCredentialVerifier` is used which reads the credentials from the config property `scout.auth.credentials` (have a look at the file config.properties).

But instead of using this `ConfigFileCredentialVerifier` you can install your own verifier, like a database verifier. You just need to adjust the `UiServletFilter`. As soon as the user presses the login button of the `login.html`, your verifier is called with the entered credentials.

Note: When you start the application out of eclipse, it will run in development mode. In this mode the login page won't be displayed, otherwise you would have to enter the credentials all the time during development. To make the login page show up nevertheless, you can either disable the dev mode by setting the property `scout.devMode` to false, or remove the `DevelopmentAccessController` from the `UiServletFilter` (that access controller is only active when `scout.devMode` is true).

Make sure to also check out the JavaDoc of `IAccessController` and the existing access controllers to better understand the authentication conecpts of Scout.